# passing of two php variables from one php page to next php page with the help of SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to pass the two variable from the below php script to the next php page that is pid and title. pid is working fine but I don't know how to take the title from SQL query and pass it to the next php script.

```
   $result= mysqli_query($bd, "select p.title, p.description from POI p where p.pid='$pid'");
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        echo "<i><h2><a href=link_comment.php?pid=$pid&title='$row[0]'>$row[0]</a></h2></i>";

        echo $row[1];
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        }
```

the below code is for getting the values from the above php script:

```
$pid=$_REQUEST['pid'];   
$title=$_REQUEST['row[0]'];
```

Comment: `$_GET['pid']` and `$_GET['title']`. Just because the title value CAME from `$row[0]` mean nothing to the link_comment.php script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

echo "<i><h2><a href=link_comment.php?pid=$pid&title='$row[0]'>$row[0]</a></h2></i>";

to this

echo "<i><h2><a href='link_comment.php?pid={$pid}&title={$row[0]}'>{$row[0]}</a></h2></i>";

Answer (score 0):

When you build the url, you are passing parameters named `pid` and `title`.

Change

```
$title=$_REQUEST['row[0]'];
```

to be

```
$title=$_REQUEST['title'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the ' you are using in `title='$row[0]'`, use {}, `title={$row[0]}`:

```
echo "<i><h2><a href=link_comment.php?pid={$pid}&title={$row[0]}>{$row[0]}</a></h2></i>";
```

And on the next page, `$_REQUEST['title'];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "<i><h2><a href=link_comment.php?pid=".$pid."&title=".$row[0].">".$row[0]."</a></h2></i>";
```

Then on the link_comment.php script:

```
$pid=$_GET['pid'];   
$title=$_GET['title'];
```

Comment: none of the above codes are working..... the main problem is coming in title='$row[0]' where title is not receiving the value of $row[0].